# ngrx reducer Property does not exist on type

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I'm using TypeScript 2.7.1 and ngrx. My Actions look like this:

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';


export const HEALTH_FORM_CONTENT_CHANGED = '[setupHealthForm] Content Changed';
export const HEALTH_FORM_TITLE_CHANGED = '[setupHealthForm] Title Changed';


export class SetupHealthFormContentChangedAction implements Action {
    public type: string = HEALTH_FORM_CONTENT_CHANGED;
    constructor(public payload: { content: string }) { }
}

export class SetupHealthFormTitleChangedAction implements Action {
    public type: string = HEALTH_FORM_TITLE_CHANGED;
    constructor(public payload: { title: string }) { }
}
export type Actions
    =
    SetupHealthFormContentChangedAction
    | SetupHealthFormTitleChangedAction;
```

my Reducer looks like this:

```
import { Actions, HEALTH_FORM_TITLE_CHANGED, HEALTH_FORM_CONTENT_CHANGED } from './setup-health-form.actions';


export interface State {
    title: string;
    body: string;
}

const initialState: State = {
    title: '',
    body: ''
}

export function reducer(state: State = initialState, action: Actions): State {

    switch (action.type) {
        case HEALTH_FORM_TITLE_CHANGED: { 
            return {
                ...state,
                ...{ title: action.payload.title }
            }
        }
        case HEALTH_FORM_CONTENT_CHANGED: {
            return {
                ...state,
                ...{ body: action.payload.content }
            }
        }
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}

export const body = (state: State) => state.body;
export const title = (state: State) => state.title;
```

However I get the following typescript errors:

```
error TS2339: Property 'title' does not exist on type '{ content: string; } | { title: string; }'.
error TS2339: Property 'content' does not exist on type '{ content: string; } | { title: string; }'.
```

The only way i've found to fix this is exporting an action with a payload of type any. How do I correctly fix this issue to retain my typings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use discriminated union types and their `switch` type guard behavior, the type of `type` has to be a string literal type (basically a string type that can only be a single value). Your `type` field is `string` even through you assign a constant to it. This happens because typescript assumes that you will want ot mutate the field so it types it as `string`. If you mark it as `readonly` and remove the explicit `string` type the field will be typed with the type of the constant (which is a string literal type) and your `switch` will correctly type check:

```
export class SetupHealthFormContentChangedAction  {
    public readonly type = HEALTH_FORM_CONTENT_CHANGED;
    constructor(public payload: { content: string }) { }
}

export class SetupHealthFormTitleChangedAction implements Action {
    public  readonly type = HEALTH_FORM_TITLE_CHANGED
    constructor(public payload: { title: string }) { }
```

[Playground sample code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20Action%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20const%20HEALTH_FORM_CONTENT_CHANGED%20%3D%20'%5BsetupHealthForm%5D%20Content%20Changed'%3B%0D%0Aexport%20const%20HEALTH_FORM_TITLE_CHANGED%20%3D%20'%5BsetupHealthForm%5D%20Title%20Changed'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20SetupHealthFormContentChangedAction%20implements%20Action%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20readonly%20type%20%3D%20HEALTH_FORM_CONTENT_CHANGED%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20payload%3A%20%7B%20content%3A%20string%20%7D)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20SetupHealthFormTitleChangedAction%20implements%20Action%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20readonly%20%20type%20%20%3D%20HEALTH_FORM_TITLE_CHANGED%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20payload%3A%20%7B%20title%3A%20string%20%7D)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aexport%20type%20Actions%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SetupHealthFormContentChangedAction%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20SetupHealthFormTitleChangedAction%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20State%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20body%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20initialState%3A%20State%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20''%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20body%3A%20''%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20reducer(state%3A%20State%20%3D%20initialState%2C%20action%3A%20Actions)%3A%20State%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20switch%20(action.type)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20HEALTH_FORM_TITLE_CHANGED%3A%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...state%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%7B%20title%3A%20action.payload.title%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20HEALTH_FORM_CONTENT_CHANGED%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...state%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)

Comment: I have added readonly per your example but the issue has not been resolved.

Comment: @that_guy Hm. I have 2.8 installed, let me check in 2.7, i'll update the answer shortly

Comment: @that_guy I checked on the playground and it works on 2.7 as well. Did you remove the explicit type from `type` ? Should be  `public  readonly type = HEALTH_FORM_TITLE_CHANGED` NOT `public  readonly type : string = HEALTH_FORM_TITLE_CHANGED`

Comment: That was it! My mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Added to the existing answer of [Titian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48992915/5668956), for my case, the error occurs if the `type` definition is a string is concatenated (this is the behavior of my IDE setting called hard wrap to auto break if the line is too long).
You will need to make sure the `type` is a concrete one single const string.

**Not working**

```
export const GET_SYSTEM_CLOSING_REPORT_OF_PROJECT_MANAGER = '[MonthClosingReportActions] Get System Closing Reports of' +
    ' project manager';
export class GetSystemClosingReportOfProjectManagerAction implements Action {
    readonly type = GET_SYSTEM_CLOSING_REPORT_OF_PROJECT_MANAGER;
    constructor(public payload: string) {}
}
```

**Working**

```
export const GET_SYSTEM_CLOSING_REPORT_OF_PROJECT_MANAGER = '[MonthClosingReportActions] Get System Closing Reports of project manager';
export class GetSystemClosingReportOfProjectManagerAction implements Action {
    readonly type = GET_SYSTEM_CLOSING_REPORT_OF_PROJECT_MANAGER;
    constructor(public payload: string) {}
}
```